# how to add subpath to localhost:8080

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, devops, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm working with Dockers and Containers using wsl on windows.

Just for testing purpose, I want to add sub-path for my demo HTML file which is by default listening to localhost:8080 but I want to make my demo HTML page to be visible at localhost:8080/main/ instead .

**here is my dockerfile:**

```
 FROM nginx:latest
 MAINTAINER : abhishek
 RUN apt-get update && apt -y install nano
 WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
 COPY index.html index.html
 COPY http.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**here is my http.conf file which i'm copying to default.conf**

```
server {
listen 8080;
server_name  localhost;

location /main/
{
    rewrite ^/main(.*)$ /$1 break;
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter '<base href="/">' '<base href="/main/">';
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
}
location /
{
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html
{
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
}
```

but it is still listening at localhost:8080 and isn't changing to localhost:8080/main/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll share what worked for me :
#Note that i was running the container for the image img007

```
docker run --name cont01 -d -p 8080:80 img007
```

#but the problem was of the container port which is 80 so I changed the code as below for my http.conf file and the sub-path localhost:8080/main/ started to display the html file.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name  localhost;

location /main/
{
rewrite ^/main(.*)$ /$1 break;
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter '<base href="/">' '<base href="/main/">';
proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
proxy_redirect    off;
proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
}
location /
{
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html
{
root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
}
```